# How to point to my own DNS (IPv6)?

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, domain-registrar

Well, I would like to point to my own DNS, as long as my domain registrar (123-reg.co.uk) does not have support for AAAA records.
But if I request to point to my own DNS, they ask me for two NS, that's ok so far, and then for IPv4 addresses and nothing more, is there any workaround for IPv6 or I have to change my domain registrar?

Comment: 123-reg does indeed not support AAAA records, but there are [more limitations](http://www.123-support.co.uk/support/answers/how-do-i-change-my-dns-settings-279/). You'd petter search for another DNS provider. I am not aware of a workaround.

Comment: I can set-up my own DNS that's not problem at all, but i can see problem in pointing to my own DNS, I'm not sure how it is done.

Comment: You should contact your registrar for that, they should add your IP(v6) nameserver addresses to the global registry.

Comment: I've already send them email about that, I'm waiting for answer and will see.

Comment: But can I somehow add my Name server into TLD DNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to change my Domain registrar. As long as they do not support IPv6.

Comment: You have a problem with glue records, I suspect.

Comment: I think so, because the domain registrar is unable to add IPv6 record for me.

Comment: You could host the nameservers in another domain under a different TLD, that way only the other domain would need IPv6 glue, and you could stay with your current registrar.

Comment: I've already changed my domain registrar, because they told me, they don't even plan support IPv6 within 1year.

Answer (score 0):

The `NS` record hold only a name, which could resolve on an IPv4 or an IPv6 :

```
. IN NS ipv6.ns.example.com.
. IN NS ipv4.ns.example.com.
```

You should be able to only provide the name of your DNS server to your registrar. They should be able to extract the IP adresses in v4 or v6 from the name of your server.

---

However your DNS server should be available on IPv4 and IPv6, even if all your records point on IPv6.

There is no garantee, even if the client is connected on the IPv6 Internet, that the DNS resolution will happend only on IPv6. For example the DNS resolver of the client could be unable to do queries on IPv6 even if it is able to respond on this protocol.

This is a transitional situation and most DNS server should be able to properly resolve names on the IPv6 Internet in the future, but for now it is safer to double stack the DNS.

Comment: I do have DNS working on IPv4, it is my domain registrar DNS, but they do not support IPv6 records (AAAA). And I'm not sure if they will have will to add my IPv6 DNS to TLD DNS.

Comment: All the nameservers should provide the same information as you can't known if the client has IPv4 or IPv6 connectivity from the protocol on which the DNS is queried. So if you want to manage your own name server you can't use theirs anymore.

Comment: I know, but they just don't offer possibility to point on my DNS on IPv6, so I'll have to change my registrar.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your domain is `example.com.`  When the recursive DNS server queries `a.gtld-servers.net.` for `www.example.com.`, it will get returned an NS record - say `ns1.example.com.` if you're running your own DNS servers.  Because the DNS server's domain name is in the same domain as the address you're looking for, there has to be a glue record held on `a.gtld-servers.net.`. The glue record is an A or AAAA record for `ns1.example.com`.

Your domain registrar is responsible for updating the TLD's DNS with the NS delegation and the glue records.

It is for the glue records that 123-reg are asking you for an IP address.  You can still host `ns1.example.com.` dual-stacked, and the authoritative record for `ns1.example.com.` can have both an A and an AAAA record - it doesn't have to match the glue record on the server you're delegating from.

You have two options if you want an AAAA glue record:

1. Change to a different registrar that supports AAAA glue.
2. Run your nameserver on a different TLD, and register the domain of your nameserver using a registrar that supports AAAA glue.

For instance, if you have `example.com` and `example.co.uk` with two different registrars, you could have `ns1.example.co.uk` as the delegation for both domains, but only `example.co.uk`would need to have a glue record (because `example.com` could resolve its name without the glue).  As long as your registrar for `example.co.uk` supports AAAA glue (and the .uk registry does, which it does) then you're OK.